# registering large amount of custom icons to mat-icon

Tags: angular, angular-material

i was wondering if there's a fast and clean way to register a whole directory to the mat-icon register mechanism.

so far what i've done is saving my icons name in a list then iterating over the list to register them, but i'm not happy about the fact that i have to add to my list new icon name every time i'm adding an icon.

here's my code:

```
const ICONS_TO_ADD = {
  'general': ['follow', 'email', 'calendar', 'recommendation', 'follow_reg', 'follow_reg_on']
};

export class AppComponent {

  constructor( private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,) {
    this.addIcons();
  }

  private addIcons() {
    for (const dirName of Object.keys(ICONS_TO_ADD)) {
      ICONS_TO_ADD[dirName].forEach(fileName => {
        const res = this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
          `${dirName}_${fileName}`,
          this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`../assets/svg/${dirName}/${fileName}.svg`)
        );
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom task to automatically generate that list from directory listing. Ideally in a file containing only this list so you can easily overwrite.

Then run that task before building